# UITableView change header title color

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, inappsettingskit

I'm styling the UITableView in [InAppSettingsKit](http://InAppSettingsKit) and want to change the color of the header title:

[image: image of tableview]

The labels `Without title` and `Text Field` should be white. How can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following line of code in table cell creation method -

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = //Your color;
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = //Your color;
```

You can refer following for more detail description, where you can find detail example of creating custom sectioned table similar to what you have mentioned - 
http://undefinedvalue.com/2009/08/25/changing-background-color-and-section-header-text-color-grouped-style-uitableview

Comment: I want to change the title of the section not the cell label.

Comment: means header of table section.

Comment: Yes, I meant the header label.

Comment: have you tried something for this, means how you are adding this label, are you using viewForHeaderInSection.

Answer (score 67):

This is an old question, but I think the answer needs to be updated.

This method does not involve defining and creating your own custom view.
In iOS 6 and up, you can easily change the background color and the text color by defining the

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view 
    forSection:(NSInteger)
```

delegate method.

For example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Background color
    view.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    // Text Color
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    [header.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    // Another way to set the background color
    // Note: does not preserve gradient effect of original header
    // header.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Taken from my post here: https://happyteamlabs.com/blog/ios-how-to-customize-table-view-header-and-footer-colors/

Swift 5.0:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        header.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    }
}
```

Comment: good job, by the way this method still works in iOS 7 so well done.

Comment: By far the superior answer.

Answer (score 5):

Implement the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method in the tableViewController. That will allow you to supply your own view for the headers, which can include a UILabel with whatever formatting you want, e.g.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UILabel *customLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    customLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    return customLabel;
}
```

Remember to set the label frame to be tall enough to space out the sections. You may wish to embed the label inside a larger UIView and return that instead to simplify positioning (e.g. if you want increase the left-padding on the label).

Comment: This is a leak.  Release or autorelease customLabel.

Comment: I was assuming he was using ARC.

Answer (score 4):

It took me a few minutes to "translate" this to Swift, but here's a working equivalent in Swift 1.2 (iOS 8). Be sure and implement `UITableViewDelegate` in your class:

```
// MARK: - VIEW METHODS
override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.delegate = self
}

// MARK: - TABLEVIEW DELEGATE METHODS
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 version:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    guard let headerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView else { return }
    headerView.textLabel?.textColor = .red // any color
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this:
[How to change text color for Section Headers in a Grouped TableView in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395171/how-to-change-text-color-for-section-headers-in-a-grouped-tableview-in-iphone-sd)
It works a treat, and I combined it with a little bit of code from the link in the answer by @rishi, and it made my life so much easier!! Although I had to tweak the coordinations of the label view a bit, but it worked like a charm.