# How do you change the colour of a section title in a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableviewsectionheader

Here is what I have at the moment.

[image]

How do I refer to this so that I can change the text colour to match my index list? The **sectionForSectionIndexTitle** worked well for adding in the correct section title but how exactly does one access the title element?

Or is it impossible and I need to redraw the view and add it with **viewForHeaderInSection**?

Comment: Yes you need to add the label in viewForHeaderInSection.

Comment: Hye man how did you add the alphabet on the right?

Comment: Its called an index list. Heres a vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYSKHna1KJk. Or another link with a great tutorial. http://www.edumobile.org/ios/indexed-table-views-in-swift/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

you can use the one of `UITableViewDelegate`'s method

**swift3 and above**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let headerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        headerView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .black
        headerView.textLabel?.textColor = .red
    }
}
```

**objective C**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class]]){
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView * headerView = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *) view;
        headerView.textLabel.textColor  = [UIColor RedColor];  
    }
}
```

for Reference I taken the model answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990880/uitableview-change-header-title-color)

Comment: Possibly my favourite answer on SO.

Answer (score 10):

One liner solution (using optional chaining):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    (view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView)?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Comment: How is this different to @Anbu.karthik's solution?

Comment: ^^ The result is the same, but this one uses optional chaining, hence resulting in one line, instead of a `if let` condition. I'll update the answer pointing this out

Comment: Works for phone and pad but having trouble changing the color of my footer when running on Mac catalyst

Answer (score 3):

Custom Title:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let title = UILabel()
    title.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Light", size: 13)!
    title.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel!.font=title.font
    header.textLabel!.textColor=title.textColor
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift Solution**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    view.tintColor = UIColor.red
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Appearance() proxy class. I usually add them in a function in AppDelegate and call them didFinishLaunching.

```
private func setupApperances() {
    UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self]).textColor = .red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own section title (header/footer) view, and it is easy.

```
class BlackTableViewHeaderFooterView : UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.backgroundColor = .black

        textLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        textLabel?.textColor = .white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class TableViewController : UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(BlackTableViewHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "\(BlackTableViewHeaderFooterView.self)")
        // do other setup
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "\(BlackTableViewHeaderFooterView.self)")
        header.textLabel?.text = "" // set your header title
        return header
    }
}
```