# UITableView header and text color

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I currently have a UITableView with multiple sections.

The header for each section is defined in the delegate like this (code adjusted for testing purposes):

```
[Export("tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:")]
public UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
  var header = tableView.DequeueReusableHeaderFooterView("TestHeaderIdentifier");
  if(header == null)
     header = new UITableViewHeaderFooterView(new NSString("TestHeaderIdentifier"));
  header.TextLabel.Text = "Section " + section;
  header.TextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
  header.ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(124, 255, 190);
  //.. Other customizations
  return header;
}
```

This seems to work fine except for one bit, the TextColor of the label.

The above code results in the following:

[image]

The background color and text itself are applied fine, but the text color remains set to the default colour. What could be the cause of this issue?

I've already tried:

- Registering the header class on the table view instead of constructing it in the delegate method (using  `RegisterClassForHeaderFooterViewReuse`)
- Not reusing/dequeing the headers at all, constructing a new instance each time

Both to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you change the colour of a section title in a tableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614268/how-do-you-change-the-colour-of-a-section-title-in-a-tableview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give your two solutions:

First, change the textColor in `WillDisplayHeaderView` function:

```
public override void WillDisplayHeaderView(UITableView tableView, UIView headerView, nint section)
{

    if (headerView is UITableViewHeaderFooterView)
    {
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView v = headerView as UITableViewHeaderFooterView;
        v.TextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
    }

}
```

Second, you can use your own custom views instead of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`:

```
public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    //var header = tableView.DequeueReusableHeaderFooterView("TestHeaderIdentifier");
    //if (header == null)
    //    header = new UITableViewHeaderFooterView(new NSString("TestHeaderIdentifier"));
    //header.TextLabel.Text = "Section " + section;
    //header.TextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
    //header.ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(124, 255, 190);
    ////.. Other customizations
    //return header;


    UIView view = new UIView();
    view.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0,100,200,50);

    UILabel label = new UILabel();
    label.Frame = view.Bounds;
    label.Text = "test";
    label.TextColor = UIColor.Red;

    view.Add(label);

    return view;
}
```