# How to change style of font in header section of grouped tableView while using static content via storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I have used storyboard to design a grouped tableView with simple, static content. I want to change the look of the section headers, but storyboard does not seem to offer this functionality, and I cannot determine how to get programmatic access to the section headers without building the interface from code.

For reference, the following SO question fully resolves the problem *in the case that the dataSource is dynamic*.

[How to change text color for Section Headers in a Grouped TableView in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395171/how-to-change-text-color-for-section-headers-in-a-grouped-tableview-in-iphone-sd)

Is a similar solution possible where the content is STATIC and I am NOT implementing the UITableViewDataSource protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you can click on a UIView object and drag it to the top of your table view in storyboard, and it will serve as it's header:

Otherwise, many of the tableview's delegate (not datasource) methods are still available even for static table views. So the delegate method:

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Will still be called. In here you can create a customized view to return as the header. This UIView can be created programmatically or in a .xib or storyboard view controller (via UIViewController.view).

**Edit 1:**

The drag and drop is for the UITableView's header, not the section. However, the method above will return a custom view for each section's header.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in response. Briefly, your suggestion did work--thank you.I tried a variation of your approach before posting this problem. I stumbled on the implementing the dataSource

Comment: Sorry about the delay in response. Briefly, your suggestion did work--thank you.

I tried a variation of your approach before posting this problem. I adopted the UITableViewDelegate protocol and implemented the viewForHeaderInSection method. Unfortunately, the UITableViewDelegate protocol includes other methods that I did NOT want to implement, so I stopped.

It turns out the storyboard adopted the UITableViewDelegate protocol, so instead of explicitly adopting it in my class interface I simply defined viewForHeaderInSection in my controller and set self.tableView.dataSource = self. Solved.

Comment: Nice. I'm glad it worked out for you. Thank you for coming back to let us know how it went.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative approach. It will change the font size of ALL table headers and footers, which is one potential drawback, but it is simpler than the approach above I think

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class],nil] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0f]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this via Storyboard and static cell, only table header, table footer, cells can use your custom views.